# jQuery trouble combining 2 functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have this working in the following way:

IF class is `.lazy` AND IF visible in viewport THEN add class `.already-visible` otherwise add class `.come-in`
BUT IF class is `.lazy-up` AND IF visible in viewport THEN add class `.already-visible-up` otherwise add class `.come-up`

:)

Here below is my code, but it triggers only the first part... please help 
Thank you thank you!

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {
    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
    return ((compareBottom <=
      viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
  };
})(jQuery);
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".lazy");
allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible");
  }
});
win.scroll(function(event) {
  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in");
    }
  });
});
(jQuery);
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".lazy-up");
allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible-up");
  }
});
win.scroll(function(event) {
  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-up");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Anybody? Just a hint would be lovely :)

Comment: Can you please provide the related HTML to reproduce/test this?

Comment: Thanks @sven-eberth. Here is my html code

`<div class="TestA lazy">
 <img src="img/xxx.jpg" alt="hello";>
</div>
<div class="TestB lazy">
 <img src="img/yyy.jpg" alt="hello";>
</div>
<div class="TestA lazy-up">
 <img src="img/zzz.jpg" alt="hello";>
</div>
<div class="TestB lazy-up">
 <img src="img/qqq.jpg" alt="final hello";>
</div>`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the html there, instead of in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you override `allMods` but use it in both `scroll` functions and expect different values/elements.
Use two variables and declare them as [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), so you get an error if you accidentally try to change them.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {
    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
    return ((compareBottom <=
      viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  const win = $(window);
  const allLazy = $(".lazy");
  allLazy.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("already-visible");
    }
  });
  win.scroll(function(event) {
    allLazy.each(function(i, el) {
      var el = $(el);
      if (el.visible(true) && !el.hasClass("already-visible")) {
        el.addClass("come-in");
      }
    });
  });

  const allLazyUp = $(".lazy-up");
  allLazyUp.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("already-visible-up");
    }
  });
  win.scroll(function(event) {
    allLazyUp.each(function(i, el) {
      var el = $(el);
      if (el.visible(true) && !el.hasClass("already-visible-up")) {
        el.addClass("come-up");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="TestA lazy"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="hello"> </div>
<div class="TestB lazy"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="hello"> </div>
<div class="TestA lazy-up"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="hello"> </div>
<div class="TestB lazy-up"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="final hello"> </div>
```

**Edit**: You can check with `hasClass()` if the element has the class `.already-visible-up` or `.already-visible-up`. If not and is visible you can add the class `come-in`/`come-up`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much @sven

Comment: Sorry @sven I just noticed that with your solution both classes `.already-visible-up` and `.come-up` are added to the divs when scrolling down... I am trying to add either `.already-visible-up` or `.come-up`

Comment: `.already-visible-up` is added on page load if the image is visible, right? So you don't  want to add `.come-up` when you scroll? Or do you want to replace `.already-visible-up` by `.come-up`?

Comment: First option is the one: if image is visible add `.already-visible-up` (linked to this class there is an animation).
... and if not visible add `.come-up` (which has a different animation)
thank you thank you!!!

Comment: And what should happen while scrolling?

Comment: When scrolling:
- if the the image is already visible nothing will happen because the transition linked to `.already-visible` already executed
- if not already visible, let say images are at the bottom of the webpage, the transition linked to `.come-up` will executes...
Hope I explained it correctly... and thanks for looking into this 

Comment: I hope I understood it correctly. I've edited the answer.

Comment: That's it! Thank you soooo much. It worked 